# Access object property from inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably trivial, but i couldn't find an answer.

I have this object:

```
        obj = {
            key1 : {val : "hi", val2 : "pizza"},
            key2 : {val : "hello", val2 : "cheese"},
            key3 : {val : "wazzup", val2 : "hamburger"}
        };
```

And this function:

```
        function foo () {
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                console.log(value.val2);
            });
        }

        foo();
```

This works quite fine.

**Question:** how can I access one specific property passing it as an argument? For example:

```
    function foo (arg) {
        $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
            console.log(value.arg);
        });
    }

    foo(val2);
```

Comment: Use `value[arg]` instead of `value.arg`.

Comment: Ah, exactly. Thank you. Also, looks like i need to improve my search skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`bracket notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors),

```
function foo (arg) {
    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
        console.log(value[arg]);
    });
}

foo(val2);
```